# Unable to do Server-Side Sorting with ag-grid in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm trying to call redux action and to pass inside the sortModel in order to get the sorted data from the server.
[Example from documentation] (https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-sorting)
Can somebody help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
...
      defaultColDef: {
        sortable: true,
        flex: 1,
        minWidth: 100,
        resizable: true,
      },
      rowModelType: 'serverSide',
    };
  }

serverSideDatasource(response) {
  return {
    getRows: function(params) {
      console.log('[Datasource] - rows requested by grid: ', params.request);
      //Redux action
      this.props.getSortedDataFromServer( params.request.sortModel);

      setTimeout(function() {
        if (response.success) {
          params.successCallback(response.rows, response.lastRow);
        } else {
          params.failCallback();
        }
      }, 500);
    },
  };
}

  onGridReady = params => {
    //Data from redux store
    const { result } = this.props.sortedData;

    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    var datasource = this.serverSideDatasource(result);
    params.api.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
        <div
          id="myGrid"
          style={{
            height: '100%',
            width: '100%',
          }}
          className="ag-theme-alpine-dark"
        >
          <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
            defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
            rowModelType={this.state.rowModelType}
            animateRows={true}
            onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
...
```